# Error When Creating a New Project in Android Studio

Tags: android

Android Studio worked fine everyday. But since yesterday, it started showing an error when I create a new project. When I hit Finish to create a new project, nothing happens except this error shows up:

```
CalledFromWrongThreadException
            Access is allowed from event dispatch thread only.
            Details: EventQueue.isDispatchThread()=false
            isDispatchThread()=false
            Toolkit.getEventQueue()=com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue@7593de93
            Current thread: Thread[ApplicationImpl pooled thread 13,4,main] 374296670
            SystemEventQueueThread: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0 1.4#AI-141.2288178, eap:false,6,main] 400805665
            "AWT-EventQueue-0 1.4#AI-141.2288178, eap:false" prio=0 tid=0x0 nid=0x0 runnable
            java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
            at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.injected.InjectedLanguageManagerImpl.access$100(InjectedLanguageManagerImpl.java:66)
            at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.injected.InjectedLanguageManagerImpl$3.daemonCancelEventOccurred(InjectedLanguageManagerImpl.java:109)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor28.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
            at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusConnect... (show balloon)
```

If I click show balloon, it shows the expanded version. It's too big so I decided to post the brief one.
I'm using Android Studio 1.4

Thank you for the help.

Comment: if you repeat create new project this error is repeated?

Comment: Yes it is. I tried so many times, but same thing happens again and again

Answer (score 6):

This is due to conflict of your installed jdk.
Go to Project Structure -> SDK Location,un check 'Use embedded JDK' checkbox and put your jdk path

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14364244)

Comment: I got same error. I tried as I mentioned. So I posted.

Comment: Thanks.Worked for me

Answer (score 6):

Go to File -> Invalidate cache / Restart.

This might clear the cache and create a fresh session for android studio.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same problem a few minutes ago and this worked for me. Just go to **Tools-> SDK Manager**. 
You can see Android SDK Location there.

Screenshot:

[image]

**Check** all 3 components and click on **Next**. Wait until it installs & updates Android SDK Location.

Screenshot:

[image]

Soon build should start and complete successfully. I hope it helps someone who's having the same problem in 2019 onwards :)

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me. Android Studio v2.2.2.

1. Click on "Configure" > "SDK Manager".
2. Confirm that "Android SDK" is selected in the left side.
3. In the right side, there will be an input field and it might have wrong location of your Android SDK.
4. Correct that input field and it must point to your Android SDK.
5. In the end, it must look like

[image: this image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably is android Studio problem.

I see similar problems, try this:

1 Save android Studio Projects.
2 Uninstall android Studio
3 Install Android Studio.

Tell us what happend.

Comment: I didn't use Android Studio for a few days. When I opened it after a few days, it worked without throwing those errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your computer. It looks like a Thread is running lose somewhere. If that doesn't work, try reinstalling as some file may be corrupt.